# select distinct data from postgres table

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like this:
[image]

I would like a query to return results similar to this:

[image]

I would like all the sales values displayed througout the table. Also, I would like the null results to be displayed in the 'other' row, is this possible? I am new to postgres and having a hard time trying to achieve this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First coalesce nulls in `device_type` to 'other',
then group by `coalesce(device_type, 'other')` and use conditional sums with `filter` clause.

```sql
select coalesce(device_type, 'other') as device,
       sum(sales) filter (where group_name = 'GROUP_A') as group_a,
       sum(sales) filter (where group_name = 'GROUP_B') as group_b,
       sum(sales) filter (where group_name = 'GROUP_C') as group_c,
       sum(sales) filter (where group_name = 'GROUP_D') as group_d
from the_table
group by coalesce(device_type, 'other');
```

Instead of `group by coalesce(device_type, 'other')` you can write `group by 1` i.e. by the first expression in the select list. It is shorter but I am not sure that it is better readable.

Comment: question, what if I wanted the group_name columns created dynamically? Example, if I were to run the same query on area2 with the device_types still the same but different types of groups, how would that work?

Comment: Well, this would change the resulting table structure dynamically. I do not think that this is supported or that it is a good idea. But still you could combine all the group_name columns into one JSON column.